# Переход по нажатию кнопки AlertDialog в другую активность

Tags: java, android

Нужно переходить в другую активность по нажатию кнопки в AlertDialog.

Имею:

```
 builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.Next, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    });
```

Пробовал стандартным способом через `intent`, но ide ругается на контекст.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Как пробовали? Покажите.

Comment: @dmtr добавил, так же просто this пробовал или getContext(), но ругается

Comment: Засуньте в метод `onClick` создания интента и вместо `Activity.this.startActivity(intent);` напишите `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: @dmtr проблема в отсутствии контекста для создания интента

Comment: Приведите весь код, всего класса.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена с помощью метода getActivity(), который получает ссылку на объект из родительского класса для контекста при создании intent'а для перехода, вот пример:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```